# Ionic 2: Slider auto height

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Is there anyway to automatically adjust the height of an Ionic 2 slider based on the content within the slides? I have a sliding card style that I also want to expand upon clicking, however, the height of the slider is restricting it.

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.slider.autoHeight = true;
}
```